# Measure execution time in Altibase DBMS

Tags: sql, database, database-performance

I need to measure the execution time in a query in the ALTIBASE DBMS.
For example, I need to now in ms the time it took a `SELECT * FROM example;`

I tried to use the methods that have some traditional DBMS like MySQL or Oracle and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some method. The first one you can use the log from `altibase` to analyze. And the other method is to coding some program that recording time from using the `SELECT` to get result. Now, I also learn to use `altibase` - We can together.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

After entering to the client with next command `isql -u sys -p manager -sysdba` you need to execute the next query

```
SET TIMING ON;
```

Next the following queries will have the execution time.